# how can i create an image array, each with a unique id using getElementById in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I have but when I try to use the image reference its value is `null`. I want to be able to use it to access another image in a table and change the `src` property to one in the `preloadImages` array. I have already made the table but I can't get a reference to the individual elements of the `preloadImages` array. I want each image to have a unique ID using `document.getElementById('id')` Please help!! Much appreciated!

```
var preloadImages = new Array();
SIZE = 52;  

for(var h=0; h<SIZE; h++){
    preloadImages[h] = new Image();  
    preloadImages[h].src = h+'.png';
    preloadImages[h].height =100;
    preloadImages[h].width = 70;
    preloadImages[h].id = "cardImage"+h+"";              
    var cardImageRef = document.getElementById("cardImage"+h+"");
    document.write(cardImageRef+'h'); //This line is for testing, it just returns null
}
```

Comment: can you show your table code?

Comment: You have created the image elements, but not added them to the document, so that they can't be found via `document.getElementById`. But why aren't you just using `preloadImages[h]` to reference it?

Comment: height and width are btw. read-only

Comment: try to add they to DOM). Are you know, that you have global `SIZE` var?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `+""`? Also, can you show us the source code for creating the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `getElementById()` unless the element exists in the DOM tree. This modification will add them to DOM:

```
for(var h=0; h<SIZE; h++){
    preloadImages[h] = new Image(70, 100);        // size here
    preloadImages[h].src = h+ ".png";
    preloadImages[h].id = "cardImage" + h; 

    document.body.appendChild(preloadImages[h]);  // add to DOM, or some parent element

    var cardImageRef = document.getElementById("cardImage" + h);
    document.write(cardImageRef + "h"); //This line is for testing, it just returns null
}
```

However, since you already have the elements referenced in an array you could simply look the element up there using the index for the id (instead of using an id at all). This tend to be faster if your page layout has several elements.

```
var image = preloadImages[index];
```

If you where using images not identifiable by index you *could* do (but probably not relevant in this case):

```
function getImage(id) {
   for(var i = 0; i < preloadImages.length; i++) {
     if (preloadImages[i].id === id) return preloadImages[i];
   }
   return null;
}
```

So you could use it here, for example:

```
for(var h=0; h<SIZE; h++){
    preloadImages[h] = new Image(70, 100);        // size here
    preloadImages[h].src = h + ".png";
    preloadImages[h].id = "cardImage" + h;              
}

document.write(getImage("cardImage0"));
```

Comment: I'm puzzled why he would need to use ids at all, or use `getElementById` to find the element when he himself just created it and it is right there in `preloadImages[h]`, or loop through the images to find the one with a particular id when he can just use the index to find it directly in the array.

Comment: @torazaburo you're absolutely right, the index works much better in this case. I had my mind set on a generic method, but this is a good point.

Comment: @torazaburo, may be because he need it in some other place, where he hasn't to array access? see `This line is for testing`

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use IDs here. In general, it's a "code smell" to construct IDs dynamically and then use `getElementById` to find them in your document. You can instead just work with the elements themselves.

After the code you posted runs, then `preloadImages` array contains the added elements. You don't need to use `getElementById` to find the element you just constructed! And as you found out, you can't use it at all until the element is inserted into the DOM, which you're not ready to do yet!

So in your table logic, you can simply insert the images you created directly using the references you already have in `preloadImages`:

```
function makeTable(images) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);

        // put the images in the TD
        td.appendChild(images[i]);
    }

    return table; // to be inserted somewhere
}

document.body.appendChild(makeTable(preloadImages));
```

I think you're getting confused because some people have gotten into the habit of thinking of IDs as the only way of referring to elements. They construct IDs by concatenating strings, then retrieve the element when they need it by using `getElementById`. In essence, they are using the document itself as a kind of global bag of things from which you retrieve things using ID as a kind of variable name. It's better in such cases to just work with the elements themselves, held in JavaScript variables or arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The function `document.getElementById()` can only be used to reference elements that have already been added to the DOM.

However, if you wish to reference images by their id you can build an object instead and use the id as a key:

```
var preloadImages = {};
SIZE = 52;

for(var h = 0; h < SIZE; ++h) {
    var i    = new Image();
    i.id     = 'cardImage' + h;
    i.src    = h + '.png';
    i.width  = 70;
    i.height = 100;

    preloadImages[i.id] = i;
}
```

Afterwards you can refer to each image object by its id like so:

```
var img = preloadImages['cardImage2'];
// do something with image
document.body.appendChild(img); // add to page
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for the help. I am quite new to javascript so I didn't understand why it wasn't working. I can now access the image with the following code without using an id at all as suggested by some of you:

    
`for(var h=0; h<SIZE; h++){`
        `preloadImages[h] = new Image(70,100);`
        `preloadImages[h].src = h+'.png';`
        `preloadImages[h].name = h;`
        `cardImageRef[h]= preloadImages[h];`
    `}`
Sorry about my formatting of code. I am new to this site too...